# How to store "key => value" pairs as strings for future parsing?

Tags: php, mysql, string, api, key-value

I use an API, and feed a DB table based on the expected parameters coming in through that API.

However, the API frequently changes, so I have a "catch-all" `TEXT` column called `unexpectedParameters` in MySQL for any unexpected items coming from the API (e.g. a new item name and value pair introduced in an update of the API), so that I don't lose them.

How should I store these unexpected `key => value` pairs so that in the future, if necessary, I can quickly pull the `unexpectedParameters` column and parse it to re-populate the updated table with the newly-introduced columns for those new parameters?

Comment: PHP `serialize()` format, or JSON-encoded, as long as you don't want to access those unknown keys/values directly from the db field will do quite nicely.

Comment: In your specific case [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) might be an option, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if I were facing that problem this second, I'd use a text field populated with JSON. That maintains the key => value connections, takes up little space, and is easily parsable.

Comment: +1 not only it's easy to parse in many languages, but some databases are including some parsing capabilities to allow some operations to stay in the server (like XML in the '90s!)

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do it would be to use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). Try this

```
<?php
 $expected_params = array('user', 'dog', 'cat');
 if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
  $unexpected_params = array();
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if(!in_array($key, $expected_params)) {
    $unexpected_params[$key] = $value;
   }
  }
 }
 $up_serial = serialize($unexpected_params);

 // Pseudo DB functions
 $this->db->set('unexpected_params', $up_serial);
 $this->db->save();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should normalize these values out into extra tables. That should help you to keep the data small, the names of unexpected parameters handy and you can process based on each parameter later on.

```
[api-table] -- 1:n -- [unexpected values] -- n:1 -- [parameter names]
```

This is especially useful if you want to mass-process the past to current via the database server itself.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.  Could you please explain with more details?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with Normalization? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Briefly, but I don't understand how you would normalize this considering you don't know in advance which unexpected parameters you will get, and how many of them there will be...

Comment: That is why there are these relations. Unepxected value is linked to the api-table's entry it belongs to. And also it is linked to the parameter names table which contains the names. In case there is an unexpected parameter, it's name will be entered into the names table if it does not yet exist. It's ID then will be used to mark the value which is being inserted of that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store it in your SQL database, a much faster solution is to use the file system.

I wrote a small piece of code to do that. It's surprisingly versatile and fast. You can find it here: [https://github.com/paragi/rocket-store]

The advantage her is that "value" can be an array. So you can store any complex information under one key:

```
require "rocket-store.php";
$rs = new Paragi\RocketStore();

// Store a value, in the configuration collection
$rs->post("configuration", $key, $value);

// Retrieve a value from the configuration collection
$value = $rs->get("configuration", $key);
```